# To define simple windows form plugin with C++

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, dll, plugins

How can I create windows form .dll's to a perticular root directory. Now, load these .dll's (FORM1) from root directory to my Main Form. How can I define plugin to do so with Visual C++/C++??

Answer (score 0):

You can manually load dll's from your *root directory*, using **LoadLibrary()**.